# Using GROUP_CONCAT on an already GROUPed query in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a large order list that I need to create, and I need to get a list of product codes and their quantities  on a per order basis.

To simplify, I'm showing an example for a single order, but the outer query will need to provide this result for every order in the system.

So far, I have the following:

```
mysql> select ProductCode,Quantity from OrderProducts where Order_ID = X;
+-------------+----------+
| ProductCode | Quantity |
+-------------+----------+
| PROD1       |        1 |
| PROD2       |        1 |
| PROD1       |        1 |
+-------------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT CONCAT(OrderProducts.ProductCode,' (',SUM(OrderProducts.Quantity),')') FROM OrderProducts WHERE Order_ID = X GROUP BY OrderProducts.ProductCode;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CONCAT(OrderProducts.ProductCode,' (',SUM(OrderProducts.Quantity),')') |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| PROD1 (2)                                                              |
| PROD2 (1)                                                              |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What I need is a GROUP_CONCAT result of the query above,but it won't let me wrap a GROUP_CONCAT around the CONCAT shown above because I think because the SUM() is already doing grouping itself. Here is what I need to get back:

```
PROD1 (2),PROD2 (1)
```

**EDIT**

I was unclear about the use of the query above. I will be using that query as a subquery within a select which will be querying on ALL orders in `Orders`. Below is an updated version of the query:

```
SELECT 
  ( 
    SELECT 
      GROUP_CONCAT(SerialNumberedProductCount) 
    FROM  
    ( 
      SELECT 
        OrderProducts.Order_ID,
        CONCAT(OrderProducts.ProductCode,' (',SUM(OrderProducts.Quantity),')') AS SerialNumberedProductCount 
       FROM  
        OrderProducts, Products 
       WHERE 
        OrderProducts.Order_ID = Orders.Order_ID AND 
        OrderProducts.Product_ID = Products.Product_ID AND 
        Products.IsSerialNumbered = 1 
       GROUP BY 
        OrderProducts.ProductCode
    ) SerialNumberedProductCountsSubQuery 
    WHERE 
      SerialNumberedProductCountsSubQuery.Order_ID = Orders.Order_ID
  ) AS SerialNumberedProductCounts 
FROM 
  Orders
```

With the above query, I am getting the following error:

`ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Orders.Order_ID' in 'where clause'`

Comment: Your table appears to be missing a PRIMARY KEY!

Comment: @Strawberry That's not a `SELECT *`, so you cannot know if a PK is missing.

Comment: I do have `Product_ID` as my `PRIMARY KEY`, but `ProductCode` is `UNIQUE`

Comment: `ProductCode` does not look `UNIQUE`, not in this table. You probably have it Unique on the `Product` table.

Comment: @ypercube That is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To apply another aggregate, you will need to wrap it in a subquery.  This will apply the aggregate `GROUP_CONCAT()` over all rows returned by the subquery though, as is the output from your desired example. Since the inner subquery only returns the one already aggregated column, there is no need for a `GROUP BY` in the outer query

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(prod_sum)
FROM (
  SELECT CONCAT(OrderProducts.ProductCode,' (',SUM(OrderProducts.Quantity),')') AS prod_sum 
  FROM OrderProducts 
  WHERE Order_ID = 'X'
  GROUP BY OrderProducts.ProductCode
) subq
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68bca/4

#### Update after re-post

To join the results of your subqueries against `Orders`, you probably ought to be joining this entire construct in instead of using a subselect.

```
SELECT 
  /* Replace these with the columns you actually need */
  Orders.*,
  SerialNumberedProductCounts.*
FROM 
  Orders
  LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT
      Order_ID, 
      GROUP_CONCAT(SerialNumberedProductCount) 
    FROM  
    ( 
      SELECT 
        OrderProducts.Order_ID,
        CONCAT(OrderProducts.ProductCode,' (',SUM(OrderProducts.Quantity),')') AS SerialNumberedProductCount 
       FROM  
        OrderProducts, Products 
       WHERE 
        OrderProducts.Product_ID = Products.Product_ID AND 
        Products.IsSerialNumbered = 1 
       GROUP BY 
        OrderProducts.ProductCode
    ) SerialNumberedProductCountsSubQuery 
    GROUP BY Order_Id
  ) AS SerialNumberedProductCounts 
  ON SerialNumberedProductCounts.Order_ID = Orders.Order_ID
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this without derived tables? Trying to keep performance in mind.

Comment: @Travis It won't have much effect on performance, unless there is more to this query than you are showing us. It's just taking the output rowset and modifying its presentation a little. This is very different from doing a subselect in the `SELECT` list for example, where the subselect is run for each row. This will only be executed once.

Comment: There is more to it, but for the ease of posting the question, I excluded it. This query will be a subquery for a `SELECT` that is querying on ALL Orders. Should I adjust my original question to include that?

Comment: @Travis But to answer directly - you will either need this subquey, or the one in Strawberry's answer (which moves the `CONCAT()` to the outside). You cannot perform 2 aggregate layers without it.

Comment: Yes, just try to optimize efficiency for the internal query. If you want it for every Order, one answer would be to change the `WHERE Order_ID = 'X' GROUP BY ProductCode` to `GROUP BY Order_ID, ProductCode`

Comment: @Travis You can include it above, but it sounds like it isn't likely to affect the outcome.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Upon applying this to my main query, the subquery is unable to use the Order ID from the outer query, giving me: `ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Orders.Order_ID' in 'where clause'`. Is it a scope issue? I can post the query if it isn't clear.

Comment: @Travis Yes post it. the stuff you have posted so far only references `OrderProducts`, not `Orders`.

Comment: @Travis Since in your real query you are using `OrderProducts.Order_ID` in the inner `CONCAT()`, add it also with the outer `GROUP_CONCAT()`, and add `GROUP BY `Order_ID` to that outer one as well.

Comment: @Travis Or join it in, which is better. added above.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski mind if we pull this into a chat? Still not working and the iterations and attempts at this query are growing by the minute :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23866/discussion-between-travis-and-michael-berkowski)

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like this

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(con) as Con
from (SELECT
    CONCAT(OrderProducts.ProductCode,' (',SUM(OrderProducts.Quantity),')') as Con
      FROM OrderProducts
      WHERE Order_ID = X
      GROUP BY OrderProducts.ProductCode
) as r
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(productcode,'(',n,')')) summary 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT productcode
            , SUM(quantity) n 
         FROM orderproducts 
        WHERE order_id = x
        GROUP 
           BY productcode
     ) x;
```